# Javascript regex format price, 2 cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have 2 cases of price format and i am stuck on the regex, i cant find any solution how to solve it.

My regex to format price: `/(\d)(\d{3})(\.)/g`

## Case 1:

```
var price             = '1000000.0000';
var decimals          = 2;
var thousandSeparator = ',';
var decimalSeparator  = '.';
var formatedPrice     = price.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\.)/g, '$1' + thousandSeparator + '$2' + decimalSeparator + '');
document.querySelector( '#case_1 span' ).innerHTML = formatedPrice;
```

Results: `1000,000.0000`

Expected: `1,000,000.0000`

## Case 2:

```
var price             = '1000000.0000';
var decimals          = 2;
var thousandSeparator = '.';
var decimalSeparator  = ',';
var formatedPrice     = price.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})(\.)/g, '$1' + thousandSeparator + '$2' + decimalSeparator + '');
document.querySelector( '#case_2 span' ).innerHTML = formatedPrice;
```

Results: `1000.000,0000`

Expected: `1.000.000,0000`

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpan2s6d/

Is it possible to achieve only using regex?

Thanks

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, i already tried that. Didn't worked for me

Comment: Try looking at the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) api, it might allow you to do what you want without regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First replace all dots with your decimalseparator. Then group the thousands.

```
price.replace(".", decimalSeparator).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);
```

Code:

```js
var price = '1000000.00';
var decimals = 2;
var thousandSeparator = ',';
var decimalSeparator = '.';
var formatedPrice = price.replace(".", decimalSeparator).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);

document.querySelector('#case_1 span').innerHTML = formatedPrice;

var price = '1000000.00';
var decimals = 2;
var thousandSeparator = '.';
var decimalSeparator = ',';
var formatedPrice = price.replace(".", decimalSeparator).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);

document.querySelector('#case_2 span').innerHTML = formatedPrice
```

```html
  <div id="case_1">Case 1: <span></span></div>
  <div id="case_2">Case 2: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: It doens't work with 4 decimals, example: "1,000,000.0000". Returns "1,000,000.0,000". Question updated.